# ruby 1.9 how to convert array to string without brackets

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, version, string-interpolation

My question is about how to convert array elements to string in ruby 1.9 without getting the brackets and quotation marks. I've got an array (DB extract), from which I want to use to create a periodic report.

```
myArray = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "2", "15", "12"]
```

In ruby 1.8 I had the following line

```
reportStr = "In the first quarter we sold " + myArray[3].to_s + " " + myArray[0].to_s + "(s)."
puts reportStr
```

Which produced the (wanted) output

> In the first quarter we sold 2 Apple(s).

The same two lines in ruby 1.9 produce (not wanted)

> In the first quarter we sold ["2"] ["Apple"] (s).

After reading in the documentation
[Ruby 1.9.3 doc#Array#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice)
I thought I could produce code like

```
reportStr = "In the first quarter we sold " + myArray[3] + " " + myArray[0] + "(s)."
puts reportStr
```

which returns a runtime error

> /home/test/example.rb:450:in `+': can't convert Array into String (TypeError)

My current solution is to remove brackets and quotation marks with a temporary string, like

```
tempStr0 = myArray[0].to_s
myLength = tempStr0.length
tempStr0 = tempStr0[2..myLength-3]
tempStr3 = myArray[3].to_s
myLength = tempStr3.length
tempStr3 = tempStr3[2..myLength-3]
reportStr = "In the first quarter we sold " + tempStr3 + " " + tempStr0 + "(s)."
puts reportStr
```

which in general works.

However, what would be a more elegant "ruby" way how to do that?

Comment: Wed Oct 23 18:16:46#8>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

Wed Oct 23 18:16:51#9>irb

irb(main):001:0> myArray = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "2", "15", "12"]
=> ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "2", "15", "12"]

irb(main):002:0> reportStr = "In the first quarter we sold " + myArray[3].to_s + " " + myArray[0].to_s + "(s)."
=> "In the first quarter we sold 2 Apple(s)."

irb(main):003:0> puts reportStr
In the first quarter we sold 2 Apple(s).

I think your issue isn't related to the version of Ruby

Comment: Sorry Leif, but your comment does not help me.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I can't reproduce your issue under 1.9 - hence a comment. I didn't think you'd appreciate an answer of "works for me!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interpolation instead of concatenation:

```
reportStr = "In the first quarter we sold #{myArray[3]} #{myArray[0]}(s)."
```

It's more idiomatic, more efficient, requires less typing and automatically calls `to_s` for you.

Answer (score 43):

You can use the [`.join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) method.

For example:

```
my_array = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"]

my_array.join(', ') # returns string separating array elements with arg to `join`

=> Apple, Pear, Banana
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you need to do this for more than one fruit the best way is to transform the array and the use the each statement.

```
myArray = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "2", "1", "12"]
num_of_products = 3

tranformed = myArray.each_slice(num_of_products).to_a.transpose
p tranformed #=> [["Apple", "2"], ["Pear", "1"], ["Banana", "12"]]

tranformed.each do |fruit, amount|
  puts "In the first quarter we sold #{amount} #{fruit}#{amount=='1' ? '':'s'}."
end 

#=>
#In the first quarter we sold 2 Apples.
#In the first quarter we sold 1 Pear.
#In the first quarter we sold 12 Bananas.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as `arrayToString()`

`array = array * " "`

E.g.,

`myArray = ["One.","_1_?! Really?!","Yes!"]`

> `=>` `"One.","_1_?! Really?!","Yes!"`

`myArray = myArray * " "`

> `=>` `"One. _1_?! Really?! Yes."`